# How to stop the uninstallation and pop up a message box when uninstalling in Safe mode using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

How to stop the uninstallation and pop up a message box (something like as shown below) when uninstalling the installed software using NSIS if the operating system is in Safe mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function un.onInit
!define /IfNDef SM_CLEANBOOT 67
System::Call 'USER32::GetSystemMetrics(i${SM_CLEANBOOT})i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    MessageBox mb_IconStop "Safe mode blah blah"
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Every line except the Call line is NSIS boilerplate. The Call line is too complicated to fully explain but it should be obvious that it is responsible for asking the OS about the safe mode state (Microsoft calls it clean boot in this context for some reason).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation.